# Microsoft Access Error in Populating Form

Tags: ms-access, error-handling

```
=DCount("[Report Number]","[qSTATS1]","[TA]='Engineering'And[Lab Section]=Electronics'")
```

I put this in the Control Source in a Textbox like previously suggested instead of a macro, and it is giving me an error within the text box. It is supposed to pull from a query.

Comment: Also eliminate a type mistake.  Are TA and [Lab Section] text types?

Comment: =DCount("[Report Number]","[qSTATS1]") and it still isn't pulling the data from the query, which is in the expression. I am at a loss, honestly. This used to work, and now, it has stopped working entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an apostrophe in front of the word Electronics.

Try this:

```
=DCount("[Report Number]","[qSTATS1]","[TA]='Engineering' And [Lab Section]='Electronics'")
```

Comment: I am still getting an error just as before.

Comment: Make sure [Report Number], [TA], and [Lab Section] are all fields in the qSTATS query and that everything is spelled correctly with no extra/missing spaces. Also, make sure the query itself can run with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Opening up the VBA and running the macro through that module fixed the issue.